# XSD.exe warning-error

Tags: xml, xsd

I have some xsd's given to me and i want to generate C# classes to create xml documents based on these classes. I have problem generating classes though from those xsd!

I get schema validation warning: Type'http://ww...../types:ExampleNameType' is not declared, or is not a simple type. Ok they gave me some xsd's declaring the types and these xsd's are named on imports section e.g.:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www..../types" schemaLocation="types.xsd"/> 
<xs:import namespace="http://www..../tms" schemaLocation="tms.xsd"/>.
```

I'm kinda newbie on XML and i cant get this xsd schema thing.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you put in all xsd files, e.g.:

```
xsd.exe /c types.xsd tms.xsd root.xsd
```